# module 'pysftp' has no attribute 'Connection' in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, pysftp

I would like to send a file through sftp with python3.6.5.
I'm trying with pysftp package which seems to be a reference.

[The doc](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/) says that latest version 0.2.9 (released in 2016) was checked for Python 3.4, not above (quite logic for that time).
I read some comments saying it works for 3.6.
I downloaded the package and try to use it, but got this mistake :
AttributeError: module 'pysftp' has no attribute 'Connection'

Can't understand why ..
Can someone help me out or have an other sftp package ? Thanks a lot !

Here is my code :

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection(host=hote, username=nom, password=mdp) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully established ... ")
```

Comment: By any chance do you have another file named pysftp.py? Showing full traceback would be helpful.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). pysftp works in Python 3.6. You are asking a wrong question. Ask about your real problem, not about your assumptions.

Comment: @buran No I have no other file name the same way

Comment: @MartinPrikryl true, I update my question

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None 
with pysftp.Connection(host='demo.wftpserver.com',username='demo-user',password='demo-user',port=2222,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully established ... ")


Result:  Connection succesfully established ...
```

I used a public and a demo server to test the connection; and added an option to ignore checking the hostkey. My python version is 3.6.5 on Mac Mojave 10.14.6

Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

BUT remove setting the hostkeys to None when you are connecting to your trusted host. Since this is important for security reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Got this error : AttributeError: module 'pysftp' has no attribute 'CnOpts' .. I wonder if my package installation is correct

Comment: This is my pysftp==0.2.9 version.  You may run this to upgrade your version.  pip install --upgrade pysftp.

Comment: indeed, installation wasn't correct. The error message is now different : UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\admin.cb\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).

Comment: great. if you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it and upvote. thanks.

Comment: Your answer improved my code but did not solved my problem. It was a problem linked to installation. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As said above, pysftp works fine with python 3.6. 
The problem was not linked to the package pysftp itself. The package was not correctly installed. I downloaded it without pip.

So `python -m pip install pysftp` solved the problem.